# Why is forfiles output not redirected to the log in my script

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd, command-prompt

. Hi,
I the script below, the forfiles command is not redirected to the txtfile.

Also, if you would do anything in the script differently I'd love your feedback.

```
@echo off
:: Date format from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY.MM.DD
set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%

:: Output all to txt
>F:\Backups\SQLBackups-%DATESTAMP%.txt (

:: Backup and Copy loop.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for %%i in (
    DB1
    DB2
    DB3
) do (
    set DATABASENAME=%%i
    set BACKUPFILENAME=F:\Backups\!DATABASENAME!-!DATESTAMP!.bak

    echo -- Backing Up Database !DATABASENAME! --
    sqlcmd -E -S DBServer -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [!DATABASENAME!] TO     DISK = '!BACKUPFILENAME!' WITH DESCRIPTION = 'Full backup [!DATABASENAME!]', CHECKSUM, INIT, COMPRESSION, STATS"
    echo.

    echo -- Copying Database !DATABASENAME!--
    robocopy F:\Backups\ Y:\DBServer\ !DATABASENAME!-!DATESTAMP!.bak
)
endlocal

:: Delete files older than 180 days
forfiles -p F:\Backups\ -s -m *.* -d "-180" /C "cmd /c del @path"
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, your `forfiles` command, executing a `del` command on a file should generate no ouput unless there is an error. So, assumming there are no errors, it will append nothing.

If you want the list of processed files appended to the log, use

```
forfiles -p F:\Backups\ -s -m *.* -d "-180" /C "cmd /c echo @path & del @path"
```